# add memo / note when pop up "Request for Permissions" in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want ask something about Request for Permissions in Facebook...
I have made an app in Facebook and can pop up the request for permissions when someone want use the apps...

and all I want to ask is, can I add some text at the pop up dialog box, before the user click allow or skip??

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Edit your app settings, section „Auth-Dialog”.

That’s the only way to add a logo, subtitle and description. You can *not* do it per login call, just in general for your app.

Use „Preview Current Dialog” on that settings page to see what it’ll look like.

Comment: Thanks CBroe...

In your comment, about logo subtitle and description..
When I edit the description, we can see "about this app" have a memo like I wrote..

but I want a memo not for that place..
I want a memo after click "go to app" which have some permission to allow or skip...

is that possible?

Comment: No, you don’t have any more possibilities to “customize” the auth dialog than the fields that are in your app settings.